# Add a ''numbre employee'' column with auto-increment

Tags: mysql

I would like to add a number employee column to my table,
this column must be auto-incremented depending on the name of the employee.
Example:

```
|Name  |employee number|operation|
|x     |   1           |      Buy|
|y     |   2           |     Rent|
|X     |   1           |     Rent|
|z     |   3           |      buy|
```

Thank you!